# how to read txt file into 2d array in java?

Tags: java

I want to read my `"@"` seperated txt file and write my 2d array.

```
String[][] Array = new String[maxLines][1]

row=sentence
column=id
```

by the way sorry my broken english. thanks

here is my txt file

```
Sözcük Anlamı (1/4)@KyrXKdh00r8
Sözcük Anlamı (2/4)@kwHMZY_KG4Y
Sözcük Anlamı (3/4)@y9zQn2_0zg8
Sözcük Anlamı → Söz Yorumu (4/4)@xbUMVW7ru-w
Cümle Anlamı (1/3)@RWq2-idYCJ8
Cümle Anlamı (2/3)@b2Ey7KLv980
Cümle Anlamı (3/3)@fd7FFJo_iyw
Paragraf (1/4)@E2XP6w7a4Iw
Paragraf (2/4)@4xix0HoygXU
Paragraf (3/4)@-9XWCKjzNic
Paragraf (4/4)@mhS-Cl22LIw
Sözcük Türleri → İsim (1/8)@15fYjVVEV8I
Sözcük Türleri → Zamirler (2/15)@wqVAscXd9fg
Sözcük Türleri → Sıfat I (3/8)@RshzRhWpCUk
Sözcük Türleri → Sıfat II (4/8)@bXjWUvDPbIA
Sözcük Türleri → Belirteç I (5/8)@-D0GowEK06c
Sözcük Türleri → Belirteç II (6/8)@En7lPNgu278
Sözcük Türleri → İlgeç Bağlaç Ünlem I (7/8)@1ab_9yXZ5GA
Sözcük Türleri → İlgeç Bağlaç Ünlem II (8/8)@f2KQnfAgQwA
Tamlamalar (1/2)@HgXisrprtUI
Tamlamalar (2/2)@DmNl2FZfLko
```

here is my sample code:

```
package readfile;
```

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("turkce.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    final int maxLines = 100;
    String[][] resultArray = new String[maxLines][1];
    int linesCounter = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine() && linesCounter < maxLines) {
        resultArray[linesCounter] = scanner.nextLine().split("@");
        linesCounter++;
    }
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println(resultArray[1][0]);
}
```

}

edit my output is
resultArray [1][0] is empty (it is my first problem)

resultArray [1][0] is S ö z c ü k A n l a m ? ( 2 / 4)  (my second problem. its output should be "Sözcük Anlamı (2/4)

thanks again

Comment: You forgot to add your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u use Java8 it is pretty simple. There is some code

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
List<String[]> list = bufferedReader.lines()
                                .map(line -> line.split("@"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
String[][] result = list.toArray(new String[list.size()][]);
```

Comment: thank you! but my array [2][0] is SÃ¶zcÃ¼k AnlamÄ± (2/4) how can I fix this character problem?